# Add suffix to a specific row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to add suffix to **% Paid** row in the dataframe, but im stuck with only adding suffix to the column names.

is there a way i can add suffix to a **specific row values**,

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```py
d={
    ("Payments","Jan","NOS"):[],
    ("Payments","Feb","NOS"):[],
    ("Payments","Mar","NOS"):[],
}
d = pd.DataFrame(d)

d.loc["Total",("Payments","Jan","NOS")] = 9991
d.loc["Total",("Payments","Feb","NOS")] = 3638
d.loc["Total",("Payments","Mar","NOS")] = 5433

d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Jan","NOS")] = 139
d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Feb","NOS")] = 123
d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Mar","NOS")] = 20

d.loc["% Paid",("Payments","Jan","NOS")] = round((d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Jan","NOS")] / d.loc["Total",("Payments","Jan","NOS")])*100)
d.loc["% Paid",("Payments","Feb","NOS")] = round((d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Feb","NOS")] / d.loc["Total",("Payments","Feb","NOS")])*100)
d.loc["% Paid",("Payments","Mar","NOS")] = round((d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Mar","NOS")] / d.loc["Total",("Payments","Mar","NOS")])*100)
```

[without suffix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zganp.png)

I tried this way, it works but.. im looking for adding suffix for an entire row..

```py
d.loc["% Paid",("Payments","Jan","NOS")] = str(round((d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Jan","NOS")] / d.loc["Total",("Payments","Jan","NOS")])*100)) + '%'
d.loc["% Paid",("Payments","Feb","NOS")] = str(round((d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Feb","NOS")] / d.loc["Total",("Payments","Feb","NOS")])*100)) + '%
d.loc["% Paid",("Payments","Mar","NOS")] = str(round((d.loc["Paid",("Payments","Mar","NOS")] / d.loc["Total",("Payments","Mar","NOS")])*100)) + '%'
```

[with suffix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUJzG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select row separately by first index value, round and convert to integers, last to strings and add `%`:

```
d.loc["% Paid"] = d.loc["% Paid"].round().astype(int).astype(str).add(' %')
print (d)
       Payments                
            Jan     Feb     Mar
            NOS     NOS     NOS
Total    9991.0  3638.0  5433.0
Paid      139.0   123.0    20.0
% Paid      1 %     3 %     0 %
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.. this is what i've been looking for.

Comment: If we have **more than one row to add suffix,** I found that by removing `.round()` works, or else we end up with `TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method`.

Comment: @HarishOsthe - How working `d.loc["% Paid"].round().astype(int)` only? Or need replace missing values by `d.loc["% Paid"].round().fillna(0).astype(int)` ?